# Is there a word for the act clearing one's nose of phlegm when having a cold?

Tags: single-word-requests

When nose is blocked due to cold and phlegm, one keeps a finger on one side of the nose and shoot the phlegm out from the other side to clear that side of the nose. What is this act called?

Comment: Do you want a word specifically for shooting mucus out of a single nostril, or is a more general term for ejecting phlegm from both nostrils and/or mouth acceptable?

Comment: The phrase is _to blow one's nose_. Handkerchiefs and tissues are often encountered in performance.

Comment: The output is called a *snot rocket* (a noun). Do you need a [verb](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+snot+rockets) with that?

Comment: My mom used to call it a "hobo blow". I guess in the 1930's - '40's it was fairly common to see transient gentlemen, who were loath to soil their only handkerchief, empty their noses in that manner. Am.E.

Answer (score 1):

[WWN Guide To Ejecting Snot From Your Nose Like A Professional Footballer...](https://waterfordwhispersnews.com/2015/10/12/wwn-guide-to-ejecting-snot-from-your-nose-like-a-professional-footballer/)
<sub>(Waterford Whispers News)</sub>

> *With **hocking** mucus from your nose becoming more and more popular among sports stars, we here at WWN have put together a handy guide to help you **snort** it like Beckham.*

Note that ***hocking*** there probably derives from ***hawking***<sup>1</sup>, which *usually* refers to material coughed up from the back of the throat and lower, not the sinuses. Whatever - I haven't got the stomach for it, but if you want all the disgusting details, follow that link and fill your boots!

---

<sup>1</sup> From the full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary...
**hawk** 1. intransitive
*To make an effort to clear the throat of phlegm; to clear the throat noisily.*
No mention of ***nasal*** passages. But I think it's the best we've got, here.

Comment: This is right and oh so gross (grotty, UK).

Comment: Actually, I just threw caution to the winds, and had a (brief) look at the linked page myself. It's obviously seriously tongue-in-cheek though - I see *Some sports stars drink **30-40 litres of milk** before each match to help with their booger game.* (Dairy products increase phlegm / mucus production! :)

Comment: Poor Alice, it's getting grosser and grosser. :)